# What is the meaning of CalendarServer's sudoers.plist?

Tags: linux, apple, calendar, caldav

Apple's CalendarServer requires a file called "sudoers.plist". According to the vast majority of installation tutorials, this file is to be taken from the examples without any further modification.

It contains a username and password tag, which by its own admittance is the only part of the file currently in use. The tags are filled with "username" and "password" as default values.

I failed to find the meaning of this file. I am surprised so few people seem to be bothered with a file called "sudoers" that contains the worlds worst username/password combination.

Does anyone know the purpose of that file?

Comment: An interesting question for sure.  You might find more Apple knowledge over at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). :)